# Passing 'this' within braces to an object of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, this

```
class District
    :public State<District>
{
public:
    typedef Citizen Man;
    using State<District>::State;
    void CheckTransition( Man& Man );
private:
    int counter = 0;
};

class Citizen
    :public TopState<Citizen>
{
public:
    Citizen();
    District object{this};                 
};
```

I am unable to understand the usage of the last line in this piece. Can some one please explain what is happening here?

Line: `District object{this};`

I would like to understand the usage of `this` in this context within the braces to an object of a class.

Comment: It's just initializing object via whatever District constructor takes a pointer to a Citizen.

Comment: Sorry. Can you please explain a bit or provide a link for more understanding

Comment: Clarify what? How object initialization works? What `this` is? Uniform initialization syntax?

Comment: Uniform initialization syntax

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization  This is an example of case 4.

Comment: @Shawn But I dont have a constructor here for class District.
Wont that be a problem?

Comment: Theres's not one in State?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Line: District object{this};
>   I would like to understand the usage of 'this' in this context within the braces to an object of a class.

A new way of initialization called brace-initialization was introduced in C++11 which makes the following possible:

```
int z{ 0 }; 
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 3, 5 }; 
Widget w1{10}; 
Widget w2{w1};
```

And it is also possible to use `this` for initialization.

From the standard 12.6.2/7 "Initializing bases and members" available [here](http://www.lcdf.org/c%2B%2B/clause12.html):

> 12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]
>   ....
>   7 Names in the expression-list of a mem-initializer are evaluated in the scope of the constructor for which the mem-initializer is specified.
>   [Example:

```
class X {
     int a;
     int b;
     int i;
     int j;
public:
     const int& r;
     X(int i): r(a), b(i), i(i), j(this->i) {}
};
```

> initializes `X::r` to refer to `X::a`, initializes `X::b` with the value of the constructor parameter i, initializes `X::i` with the value of the constructor parameter `i`, and initializes `X::j` with the value of `X::i`; this takes place each time an object of class X is created. ]
>   [Note: because the mem-initializer are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, **the `this` pointer can be used in the expression-list of a mem-initializer to refer to the object being initialized**. ]

It's safe to use `this` pointer in initialization-list as long as it's not being used to access uninitialized members or virtual functions.